# Is this vector a linear combination of these vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am having a bit of a trouble understanding linear combinations. 
Say, for example, I have a vector 
$$Z=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    4  \\
    -5  \\
    -4  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Would this vector be a linear combination of 
 $$X=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1  \\
    -1  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
and  $$Y=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2  \\
    -1  \\
    -2  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Just try to write $Z$ as $aX+bY$. In other words, solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a+2b=4\\a-b=-5\\-a-2b=-4.\end{array}\right.$$Does it have solutions? Then $Z$ is a linear combination of $X$ and $Y$. Otherwise, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, because the matrix with columns these vectors coordinates:
$$\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{rrr}
4&1&2\\-5&1&-1\\-4&-1&-2
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}$$
has rank $2$.

Answer (score 0):

For this to be a linear combination, we would be able to say that \begin{align}Z&=aX+bY\\
\begin{bmatrix}4\\-5\\-4\end{bmatrix}&=a\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\-2\end{bmatrix}\end{align}

for $a,b$ integers.

So, we have \begin{align}4&=a+2b\tag{1}\\
-5&=a-b\tag{2}\\
-4&=-a-2b\tag{3}\end{align}

$(1)-(2)$:
\begin{align}4--5&=(a+2b)-(a-b)\\
9&=a+2b-a+b\\
9&=3b\\
b&=3\end{align}

Substitute $b$ in $(3)$:

\begin{align}-4&=-a-2\times 3\\
-4&=-a-6\\
a&=-6+4\\
a&=-2\end{align}

Finally check this in $(1)$:

\begin{align}a+2b&=(-2)+2\times 3\\
&=-2+6\\
&=4\end{align}

Therefore, we can say that

$$Z=-2X+3Y$$ and so $Z$ is a linear combination of $X$ and $Y$